# Using the reply to mv -i in a bash script

Tags: bash, prompt

After some research, I have not found elsewhere how to achieve what I want to do so I'm posting here.

I have a bash script which make use of the following command:

```
mv -iv "${file}" "${file}.bak"
```

In fact, I use `mv` in my script but it is aliased to `mv -iv`

If I execute the script more than one time, I'll be prompted to overwrite the existing `${file}.bak`

What I want to do is to execute a code depending on my answer.

Replying [Nn] execute a command. Replying [Yy] execute another one.

I know how to record an answer with `read -p` when I prompt from my script but I don't know how to capture the answer of the `mv -i` command from my script.

I tried the following (which I know is wrong because the `mv` command executes properly independently no matter what my answer is):

```
if mv -iv "${file}" "${file}.bak"; then
  # Do stuffs
else
  # Do other stuffs
fi;
```

In short, I want to capture from a bash script my answer to the `mv -i` command prompt to give control to different logic.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Why rely on `mv -i`, rather than doing the prompt *directly in the script itself*?

Comment: ...POSIX *does* specify `mv -i`'s behavior, but it doesn't specify important details about that behavior. You could have a perfectly compliant `mv`, for instance, that instead of asking if you want to continue, asks if you want to skip, and thus inverts the meaning of the response. Assuming things about user-interface behavior in a script is typically a questionable choice, because user interfaces, as opposed to programmatic ones, are built with the expectation that they can change over time and are being operated by an entity that can read and follow human-language instructions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i thought about this but i don't want to un-alias my mv -i. Calling mv in my script make it interactive by default.

Comment: Eh? Scripts run in their own interpreter, so they aren't affected by aliases -- unless you're *sourcing* this script rather than *executing* it. (Also, aliases are turned off by default in noninteractive shells, which typically also applies to a shell launched to run a script).

Comment: That said, if you want to bypass any function or alias wrapping `mv`, you can just have your script run `command mv ...`, which will run the command as-is, no aliases involved.

Comment: Charles is right. Use "command mv ..." and prompt the user by yourself - it's the best way to go.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy my aliases are sourced from .bash_profile along with my custom functions where the mv -i happens

Comment: Thanks for the command mv tip :) I was not aware of a method to come back to the original command.

Comment: Ahh -- so this isn't a script, but a function. Makes sense, then; use `command` for that case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy script is the wrong term indeed. Though I didn't know an executed script doesn't take into account aliases sourced in .bash_profile given the fact that I'm on mac and each shell is a login shell and then should source my aliases. I'll run an experiment to test. Thanks again for the tip